How to extend PersistedGrantDbContext with Custom DB context in Duende Server v7
When building an IDP with Duende Server v7 and .NET 8 I am trying to extend the PersistedGrantDbContext that is baked into the nuget package with a few additionaly DbSet entities custom to my application, specifically using a custom model called TenantPersistedGrant for the PersistedGrants object instead of PersistedGrant.
Here is my custom db context implementation
    `public class IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext : PersistedGrantDbContext<IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext>
    {
        private readonly OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions;

        public IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext()
            : this(new DbContextOptions<IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext>(), new OperationalStoreOptions())
        {

        }

        public IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext> 
            options)
            : this(options, new OperationalStoreOptions())
        {
        }

        public IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext>  
            options, OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions)
            : base(options)
        {
            this.storeOptions = storeOptions;
        }

        // These are defined in the Duende base class
        // We need to override them using "new" to use our TenantPersistedGrant and DeviceFlowCodes
        public new DbSet<TenantPersistedGrant> PersistedGrants { get; set; }

        public new DbSet<DeviceFlowCodes> DeviceFlowCodes { get; set; }

and here is my Startup.cs file
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                 {
                     options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                     options.DefaultSchema = Schemas.Identity;
                     options.ConfigureDbContext = b => { b.UseNpgsql(loginDbConnectionString, 
                         opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))
                         .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention(); };
                 });

            //services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();

            // moved to AddOperationalStore above
            //services.AddSingleton<TokenCleanup>();
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext>(ops =>        
                  ops.UseNpgsql(loginDbConnectionString));

My first question is, is this possible? Can you extend the PersistedGrandDbContext? And second of all, how would you do it. Additionally, the migrations and the host project are in two separate projects within the solution.
I was able to generate migrations for the custom db context but unable to apply them with the error
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[NI.Security.IdentityProvider.IdentityServer.Data.Migrations.IdentityServer.IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'NI.Security.IdentityProvider.IdentityServer.Data.Migrations.IdentityServer.IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

